# Typescript Twitter Bootstrap not injectable?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, typescript, typescript1.5

I tried

```
tsd install jquery --save
tsd install bootstrap --save
```

and tsd.json would be

```
 {
   "version": "v4",
   "repo": "borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped",
   "ref": "master",
   "path": "typings",
   "bundle": "typings/tsd.d.ts",
   "installed": {
     "jquery/jquery.d.ts": {
       "commit": "c5a2f44bab06cf9f2bcc14530171daac1cebff6c"
     },
     "bootstrap/bootstrap.d.ts": {
       "commit": "c5a2f44bab06cf9f2bcc14530171daac1cebff6c"
     }
   }
 }
```

and tsd.d.ts was

```
/// <reference path="jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="bootstrap/bootstrap.d.ts" />
```

so, I thought I could do

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/tsd.d.ts" />

import $ = require('jquery');
$('#modal').modal();
```

But I've got this Warning.

`Uncaught TypeError: t(...).modal is not a function`

Any ideas ?

Comment: This should work just as you wrote it, what is the actual error? you wrote t(...).modal is not a function. but I don't see t(...)

Comment: After compiling , and the browser console shows below messages `Uncaught TypeError: t(...).modal is not a function`. I guess this means bootstrap is not injected into jQuery :(

Answer (score 0):

The provided code sample:

```
import $ = require('jquery');
$('#modal').modal();
```

Works fine [as shown in the test file](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/c5a2f44bab06cf9f2bcc14530171daac1cebff6c/bootstrap/bootstrap-tests.ts#L8)

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is aimed for development time only. If you are having runtime issues it's probably because you didn't include some scripts.

Comment: Do you know how I should include not-included scripts into it ? :s

Comment: The same way you added jquery to the project (Probably in your index.html), add the missing file (Probably the bootstrap files)

Answer (score 0):

The instructions that you provide:

> `tsd install jquery --save`
>
> `tsd install bootstrap --save`

Worked for me. I have in my main component (`app.component.ts`) the following:

`declare var $:JQueryStatic`

And I have a component for modals where I use the following without any complains:

`@ViewChild('modal') modal: ElementRef`

`ngAfterViewInit() {
    $(this.modal).modal()
}`

I hope it works for you too!